# How to use a String in a List dart?

Tags: dart

How to turn a String into a List in Dart? I'm sharing some code to let you know what I want to achieve.

```
String testString = "'banana', 'apple', 'peach'";
List testList = [testString];
print(testList); // This is where I want to get 'banana' instead I get the whole String back.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `split` method is what you need.

it will split the string at matches of pattern and returns a list of substrings.

```dart
String testString = "banana,apple,peach";

List testList = testString.split(',');
print(testList);
```

check out [this link](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/String/split.html) for more info.